# Differences between the Query Count metric and Query Execution Count metric in Google Bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am building monitor dashboard to keep track of the number of interactive queries for my project. I came across 2 metrics:

- Query Count
- Query Execution Count
  Based on the given description of Google, Query count is total number of in-flight queries and Query Execution Count is number of successfully executed queries. I wonder if I understanded it correctly.

Trying to google around but could not find any additional docs.

Comment: Hi, sounds like you have already answered your own question, are you looking for confirmation that this is indeed correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Just want to make sure if I understand it correctly. Thanks!